# character taking 6 bytes

Tags: java, oracle, character-encoding

We are trying to save the below string which is actually a name in db, we make some api call and we get this name:

株式会社エス・ダブリュー・コミュニケーションズ

While saving through our code (as in servlet - hibernate - database), we get an error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "NAME_ON_ACCOUNT" (actual: 138, maximum: 100)
```

this is 23 characters but looks like it's taking 6 bytes per character, that would only make it 138.

Below code gives me 69:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = string.getBytes("UTF-8");    
System.out.println(utf8Bytes.length);
```

And this gives me 92:

```
byte[] utf8Bytes = string.getBytes("UTF-32");
System.out.println(utf8Bytes.length);
```

I will surely check `NLS_CHARACTERSET` and see the IO classes but have you ever seen a character taking 6 bytes? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Read this and see if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063148/java-unicode-where-to-find-example-n-byte-unicode-characters

Comment: +1 for the above link. Take note of the mention (in a comment to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6066442/240733)) of the [**CESU-8 encoding**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8) , which Oracle DBs are said to be using and which can result in 6-byte "UTF-8" characters.

Comment: Are you using CHINESE_CHINA.WE8ISO8859P1?

Comment: @stakx - All the 23 characters quoted in the question belong to the BMP, thus needing only 69 bytes total under the CESU-8 encoding.

Comment: @Jirka - Then any idea why I get an exception where oracle thinks it's 138 long instead of 69?

Comment: @pankajgambhir - Zdenek's answer gave you a few.  Do you mind if I ask you to recover a few characters using `substr` function and share what you see?  For example, `SELECT substr(NAME_ON_ACCOUNT, 1, 1)`

Answer (score 3):

It probably holds HTML entities in a string. Like `&#29123;` or possibly the URL style, `%8C%9A`. Or maybe UTF7, like `[Ay76b`. (I made up those values, but your actual ones will be similar). It is always a pain to rely on any framework with character encoding because its authors were likely U.S. or European, both sufficing with simple ANSI where one byte equals one character.
If you managed to understand your encoding and converted it to the real UTF8 or even UTF16, it would take up less space in this particular case.

Comment: @Alex - No I am not using chinese china encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You probably literally have:

```
\u682a\u5f0f\u4f1a\u793e\u30a8\u30b9\u30fb\u30c0\u30d6\u30ea\u30e5\u30fc\u30fb\u30b3\u30df\u30e5\u30cb\u30b1\u30fc\u30b7\u30e7\u30f3\u30ba
```

See:

```
"\u682a\u5f0f\u4f1a\u793e\u30a8\u30b9\u30fb\u30c0\u30d6\u30ea\u30e5\u30fc\u30fb\u30b3\u30df\u30e5\u30cb\u30b1\u30fc\u30b7\u30e7\u30f3\u30ba".length();
//23, or 69 UTF-8 bytes
```

Vs:

```
"\\u682a\\u5f0f\\u4f1a\\u793e\\u30a8\\u30b9\\u30fb\\u30c0\\u30d6\\u30ea\\u30e5\\u30fc\\u30fb\\u30b3\\u30df\\u30e5\\u30cb\\u30b1\\u30fc\\u30b7\\u30e7\\u30f3\\u30ba".length();
//138, or 138 UTF-8 bytes
```